# Meaning of "curl" in the context below

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> A young female was dancing in an open
>   space between the crowd and the fire. At first,
>   Gringoire could not decide whether she was a
>   human being, a fairy, or an angel. The
>   golden-skinned girl was slender, elegant, and
>   graceful. Gringoire watched as she played a
>   tambourine and danced on an old Persian
>   carpet spread on the ground. Her beautiful
>   black eyes flashed like lightning.
>   Every eye was fixed upon her, every mouth
>   open. She seemed like a supernatural creature.
>   Just then, one of her **curls** got loose, and a
>   small brass object fell from it. She bent down
>   to pick it up. At that moment, Gringoire
>   realized that the lovely creature was indeed
>   human. “Aha!” he thought. “A gypsy!”

Dose it relate to hair and mean: the curl of her hair?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it relates to hair. She either has naturally curly hair, or it has been made that way. She seems to have been wearing ornamental brass items in her hair.

[image: Woman with curly hair]
[image]
[image]